# virtuemart currency of indian rs is 0.0000 and i want to be as 0.00

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

the price display is virtuemart shows 0.0000 in-spite making a lot many changes it still shows 0.0000 instead of 0.00

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Login to Admin - > Virtuemart -> Configuration -> Currencies -> Choose your currency -> Set the Decimals
```

Its done!

Hope its helps..